# asyncio task from within cannot change global INT but can change LIST

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am running an asyncio task that collects system (monitoring) information. I like to pass on a value to a variable to be used in another task.
I am not awaiting and returning values, but like to keep the task running.
It works when I use a list but not for a float or INT. any help is much appreciated

```
cpuList = [1]
teststore = 0

sync def data_collect(delay):
    while True:
        cpu_val = psutil.cpu_percent(interval=0)
        teststore = cpu_val
        cpuList.append(cpu_val)
        print(f'from within {teststore}')
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        time.sleep(delay)

async def main():  
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(data_collect(1))
    while True:
        print(f'from main {cpuList}')
        print(f'from main {teststore}') 
        time.sleep(1)

## output:
# from within 16.9
# from main [1, 16.9]
# from main 0
# from within 2.9
# from main [1, 16.9, 2.9]
# from main 0
# from within 1.3
# from main [1, 16.9, 2.9, 1.3]
# from main 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `global teststore` from the `data_collect` function.

In Python, you must use the `global` keyword (or `nonlocal` for nested functions) in order to *assign* to a name defined in a global/non-local scope.

`cpuList.append(cpu_val)` works since you're not assigning to the `cpuList` name, but calling a method on the object the name `cpuList` is assigned to. (`cpuList = cpuList + [cpu_val]` would not work.)

That aside, you might want to consider not using global variables at all, but pass an object to the `data_collect` function:

```
async def data_collect(delay, values):
    while True:
        cpu_val = psutil.cpu_percent(interval=0)
        values.append(cpu_val)
        await asyncio.sleep(delay)


async def main():
    values = []  # modified by the async task
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(data_collect(1, values))
    while True:
        print(values)
        time.sleep(1)
```

Also, considering the two coroutines might not be running in perfect lockstep, this also opens up being able to use an `Event` for synchronization:

```
import asyncio


async def data_collect(delay: float, values: list, signal: asyncio.Event):
    while True:
        cpu_val = psutil.cpu_percent(interval=0)
        values.append(cpu_val)
        await asyncio.sleep(delay)
        signal.set()


async def main():
    values = []  # modified by the async task
    signal = asyncio.Event()
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(data_collect(1, values, signal))
    while True:
        await signal.wait()  # wait until the other task informs it has new data
        signal.clear()
        print(values)
```

## EDIT

If you really do need to also modify an integer, you'll need to "box" it into e.g. a class instance:

```
class CollectedData:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cpu_value = 0
        self.values = []
 

async def data_collect(delay, collected_data):
    while True:
        cpu_val = psutil.cpu_percent(interval=0)
        collected_data.cpu_value = cpu_val
        collected_data.values.append(cpu_val)
        await asyncio.sleep(delay)


async def main():
    cd = CollectedData()
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(data_collect(1, cd))
    while True:
        print(cd.cpu_value, cd.values)
        time.sleep(1)  # or other synchronization
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. i tried it and it works for the list. still not able to pass on a INT or float. Will I  need the global parameter for that?
will also try your synchronization suggestion